# Developers - Creating a successful plan for a new application?

Tags: database-design, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm, project-planning

We are wanting to have developers build an in-house payroll and time sheet application using symfony2/doctrine2.

We are simply at conceptual stage at this point and this will be our first time and getting developers to build an application for our company. Hence, it is very important to us that we provide the most valid and important information to what will be our new developer team.

So my question to this community is if you could please advise me of tools and/or documents that will help me define and provide a developers team with the information they require to make not only the project successful but also clear from day dot.

I have played around with ORM Designer in getting the backend in order and to give visual idea of relationships and inheritance. Please let me know of any other tools of value.

Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can post your Question here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

And by the Way check (RUP) you http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/rup/.

Best Regards

Comment: I have now posted this question on StackExchange:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/124704/developers-what-you-want-to-see-before-you-start-any-project

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the following tools while planning a project. They help to keep team on the same page.

1. Wireframe Software. I use [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)
2. DB designer. I use [DeZign](http://www.datanamic.com/dezign/)
3. Powerpoint

Communicate your idea/concept to developers frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, don't go with anyting that's not [Agile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development). Avoid [Waterfall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model) like plague.